# How does centering affects the interpretation of the marginal effects?

Tags: regression, interaction, centering, marginal-effect

I am trying to understand how centering continuous variables in a linear regression that includes an interaction term between two continuous variables, affect the interpretation of marginal effects. Assuming that the model would look something like this (Y, X and Z are continuous):

Y = b0 + b1X + b2Z + b3XZ

Using STATA's margin command I can find the marginal effects

```
margins, dydx(X) at((mean) Z) vsquish
```

The values in the margins command gives the amount of change in **Y** with a one unit change in **X** while holding **Z** constant at its mean.

Now, my question is how does this interpretation change when both both **X** and **Z** are centered. 
Because centering changes the coefficients of the main effects, margins command would produce different results and I am not sure how to interpret them.